# How to disable mongodb index while update large collection

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

My requirement is to update or add an array field into large collection. I've index on filed "Roles". While update this collection it is taking arounf 3 miniutes .. Before creating index on "role" filed it was taking less than 40 sec to update/add fileds in the collection. We need the index to read the collection . But while update it makes trouble. Is it possible to disable index while update in mongodb.. Is there any funtions available with mongo? My mongodb version is 2.6.5

Please advice.

Comment: I guess what is taking long is creating the index. So if you disable it for a while you need to rebuild/update it afterwards. Other databases have options to update indices async, maybe thats worth a search.

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of index you use.

Comment: @tarion : We are using Multikey Index on an array filed

Comment: @tarion: Yes. We have to disable index for while. Mongodb will supoort index disable? How could we do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Mongodb Indexes are updated synchronously with the insert/update. There is no way to pause the update of Indexes.

If your indexes are already created then you have two options

1. Drop the index and recreate the index, but it will have the following impacts

   1. Queries executed at the time of the insert/update is happening will miss the index.
   2. Rebuilding index is too expensive
2. Wait for the index to be updated

Comment: So there is no option to disable index in mongoDb Like oracle. Only we can drop and re create? Is there any other work arounds?

Comment: No option to disable index in mongodb, either you can drop and recreate the index  or wait for the insert/update to complete.

Answer (score 1):

```
Queries will not use partially-built indexes: the index will only be usable once the index build is complete.
```

Source: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-creation/

That means your index will block any query on the field/collection as long as the index is not complete. Therefore your have no chance but waiting for the index to be updated after adding new data.

Maybe try using another index.

Comment: I'm not creating index.. This is existing index.. We faced query slowness while read. So two weeks back we created required index.But now we have to update collection. Now the problem with update.

Comment: Which of these is the "required" index? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/ Have you tried different kinds?